# What the proper way to make a debian package launch an app at startup?

Tags: package-management, autostart, debian-installer

I have created a debian package that contains the following files

1. `mypackage.desktop`
2. `mypackage`
3. `control`
4. `copyright`
5. `packagedeb.sh`
6. `mypackage.jar` (generated from my source code)

I wrote some commands inside the `mypackage` file like:

```
cp usr/share/applications/mypackage.desktop  ~/.config/autostart/
```

to copy the `.desktop` file into autostart directory.

But I cannot see `mypackage.desktop` file inside autostart.

How can I create a debian package that copies a `.desktop` file into the `autostart` folder to launch my app at startup?

I am using [these instructions](http://pygmalion.nitri.org/create-a-debian-package-from-an-executable-jar-592.html).

Comment: Apart from the question: I don't think it is the correct/decent procedure for any package to make unnoticed, unmentioned changes locally while installing without specific confirmation from the user.